# What is the use of restore in KineticJS?

Tags: kineticjs

So, I'm a newbie in Kinetic JS. Can anyone please help me out... the hello world still appears.

```
Here is my codes. thanks


**http://notepad.cc/xoufugi29**
```

Answer (score 0):

It pops the settings off of the top of the stack. If you draw a circle or anything using those settings, It will be on top.

Comment: yeah. but it keeps displaying on the stage. it should be on the shape only :(